# How to generate TextView dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]i have an app in which i want a  layout in which two textview one align on left side other on right side.right now i am getting textview which is not getting align,how to do that i dont know.please help me to get it.

```
 LinearLayout relativeLayout = null;

        relativeLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext());
                    relativeLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams relativeLayoutParams;

                    final TextView[] textView = new TextView[3];

                    // 1st TextView
                    textView[0] = new TextView(getContext());
                    textView[1] = new TextView(getContext());
                    relativeLayoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(width,
                            LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                    textView[0].setPadding(10, 10, 5, 5);
                    textView[0].setText("");
                    textView[0].setId(1); // changed id from 0 to 1
                    textView[0].setText(object.getCCInfoLeft());

                    textView[0].setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);

                    if (textView[0] != null
                            && !textView[0].getText().equals("null")) {

                        relativeLayout.addView(textView[0], relativeLayoutParams);


                        textView[1].setText("");
                        textView[1].setTextAlignment(Gravity.RIGHT);

                        textView[1].setText(object.getCCInfoRight());
                        textView[1].setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);

                        textView[1].setPadding(100, 10, 5, 5);

                        LinearLayout.LayoutParams rightGravityParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
                        rightGravityParams.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
                        relativeLayout.addView(textView[1], rightGravityParams);

                    }
```

Comment: What's up with the large indentation?

Comment: Also, can you reduce this to a simpler example? There is a lot of code which is commented out so apparently has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: @  Code-Apprentice done

Comment: Are you trying to align the text within the text view or align the text view within its parent container?

Comment: @user3683036 post a picture what it looks like

Comment: Can you also fix the indenting?

Comment: @   Rod_Algonquin post the picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand right, you are trying to put the TextViews side by side?

In this case, you should use alignParent parameter, try this:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams TVparams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)yourRightTextView.getLayoutParams();
TVparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
//add next line just if you want it in the same line of the left one
TVparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, R.id.yourLefttextView); 

yourRightTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: What kind of error? Did you notice that the last argument is the ID of the text view? Recheck

Comment: yes i notice,but textview is also genrating run time,so addRule is asking me to change the textview into int.right now i pass the textView[1] instead of R.id.textView[1]

Comment: Again, you need to pass the ID of your text view. Set to each text view a unique id, then pass in the last argument textView[index].getId(), instead of the current arg. Set the Id of each with setId(wantedId), as you did to textview[0]

Comment: @  Reuven Chacha it is giving null exception on
TVparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);

Comment: TVparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT, textView[0].getId());

Comment: I cant get which kind of error you get, compilation? RunTime? post the error please. by the way, notice that the Id you set to TextViews has to be bigger than 0